# Quotients of T(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I want to prove that any finitely generated algebra can be written as a quotient algebra of $T(V)$, the tensor algebra where $V$ is a vector space. I was hoping to use the universal property to do this, that every linear map $\phi:V \to A$ has a corresponding homomorphism $\Phi:T(V) \to A$ but I'm struggling to turn this into an isomorphism. Is it possible to start with a surjective map and use the first isomorphism theorem?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, find a $V$ big enough to map onto a generating set for $A$. Once you have your surjection $\Phi$, quotient by the kernel to get an isomorphism.

Comment: That's helped, thanks